# Accordion + easing scrolling jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, accordion

Console error:

```
TypeError: $(...).accordion is not a function
```

Jquery in file `calljq.js` in worpdress (twentytwelve child theme ):

```
$(function() {
    $('#st-accordion').accordion();
});
```

I'd like accordion + easing scrolling in this page:

http://www.lab-360.it/test-acs/?attachment_id=67

Click on "Comment" and jquery show comment scrolling to top of the page.

Here is source :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js?ver=3.9.1" type="text/javascript" style=""></script>
<script src="http://www.lab-360.it/test-acs/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/js2/jquery.accordion.js?ver=3.9.1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.lab-360.it/test-acs/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/js2/jquery.easing.1.3.js?ver=3.9.1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.lab-360.it/test-acs/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/js2/calljq.js?ver=3.9.1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have tried in this way:

```
$('#st-accordion').accordion();
```

It's ok in console but accordion and scrolling doesn't work.

Is it a conflict?

Comment: is the accordion from jQuery UI lib?

Comment: i don't know but it's working fine in another wordpress: http://www.raccontolimpresa.it/?p=331

Comment: It's probably not. In that way, it's kind of hard to determined what's the issue :/

Comment: If in html i put all 4 scripts jquery at last and if i deactivate jquery-migrate.min.js and jquery.js in wp-includes/js/jquery it accordion-easing works, but the others js no...

Comment: maybe i have solved: custom header only with js useful:
<?php include (get_stylesheet_directory() . '/new-header.php');  ?> 
Less interesting as solutiion than a page with clean code, but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the root of the issue is that you don't have the accordian action wrapped in a document ready function, like the following...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#st-accordion').accordion();
});
```

It makes sure that the JS doesn't fire until the page has loaded and therefore all of html and other js objects are available.  It also is inline with what WP tells you to do b/c they use jQuery no-conflict.  More details about that are about half way down the following page.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Also, and this really may not matter, but it looks like you are including 2 different versions of jQuery on the page.  1.6.3 and 1.11.  I usually advise to just use the one provided with WordPress but if you need the older one, I'd remove the newer call.